# How to totally wrap an object without shrinking the orginal shape?

Tags: shrinkwrap

[image]Dear Blender users

I want to redraw something similar to the attached shape. I tried "Shrink wrap" modified but it fails. Can you guide me on this?

Comment: Hi, congrats on your first question here!  That's a great graphic, but (IMHO) it's not clear what you're trying to do.  Drape the MECH elastronics over the Sciatic Nerve?  Make the nerve?  More detail might be helpful.  Also, it's sometimes a good idea to post your blend file, or a truncated version of it that has the problem.  Not sure about this time, but just so you know, the Blender StackExchange has its own service to share blend files:  https://blend-exchange.com/help

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple possibilities to do this.

One is using the simple deform modifier:

[image]

result:

[image]

another possibility is creating and modeling a curve and using the curve modifier and animating the planes position:

[image]

result:

[image]

> Note: Both examples require the plane to be subdivided multiple times
> to get a smooth animation.